# Getting java.util.ConcurrentModificationException even when I am not adding to or removing from an ArrayList

Tags: java, list, collections, foreach, iterator

```
public void modifyList(String key, List<Person> persons, String value) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(key)) {
        for (Person person: persons) {
            if (person!= null && key.equalsIgnoreCase(person.getName())) {
                person.setValue(value);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above mentioned code, I am getting java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in the third line. Also, the occurrence of the exception is rare. What could be the reason for this.

Comment: Is it possible that more than one thread access that same List<Person> instance at the same time?

Comment: Change your loop to: `iter = value.iterator(); for(;iter.hasNext();) {..}`

Comment: You pass the list into person.setValue(). What does the setValue method do?

Comment: Sorry, I missed few things. Now, I have corrected it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun While that solves the exception, I think it's worth while finding out **why** this exception is thrown.

Comment: Interesting. As from what I understand, the list has not been changed (except value of one object), and hence ConcurrentModification should not be thrown.

Comment: Executed this code, but didn't get any exceptions. Is there any other piece of code that you haven't posted here?

Comment: Especially considering the exception is rare, I strongly suspect a concurrency problem, as @Eran hinted to. His question needs an answer.

Comment: This method is there in a Parent class and there are many child classes that are using this method.